# Drupal 7 - custom View with custom table, no data showing up

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I wrote a module to interface with Views 3 using Drupal 7, but when I create a view using my custom table as a data source, no data shows up.  Here's my schema from MySQL:

```
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title       | mediumtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Department  | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| credits     | int(10)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | longtext   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And here's the hook override in my_module.views.inc:

```
function my_module_views_data() {
  $tableName = 'My_Awesome_Table';
  $data = array();
  $data[$tableName]['table']['group'] = t('Courses');

  $data[$tableName]['table']['base'] = array(
    'field' => 'id', 
    'title' => t('Courses'), 
    'help' => t("Contains courses, departments, and descriptions.")
  );

  $data[$tableName]['title'] = array(
    'title' => t('Course name'), 
    'help' => t('Course name'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ), 
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ), 
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    ),
  );

  $data[$tableName]['Department'] = array(
    'title' => t('Course department'), 
    'help' => t('Course department'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ), 
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ), 
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    ),
  );

  $data[$tableName]['credits'] = array(
    'title' => t('Credits'), 
    'help' => t('Number of credit hours'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'argument' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric'),
    'filter' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric'),
    'sort' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_sort_numeric')
  );

  $data[$tableName]['description'] = array(
    'title' => t('Course description'), 
    'help' => t('Course description'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ), 
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ), 
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    ),
  );

  $data[$tableName]['id'] = array(
    'title' => t('Unique identifier'),
    'help' => t('Primary key for table'),
    'field' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_field'),
    'argument' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric'),
    'filter' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric'),
    'sort' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_sort_numeric'));

  return $data;
}
```

Does something look wrong with my mapping?  When I create a View, I'm trying a simple Unformatted List and just displaying each field with a label.  The only field that shows up with data is `id`, and all of the `id` values from my table are there.  I tried adding a Filter to the View so that Course Department != *blank* and Course Name != *blank*, which didn't eliminate any results (based on the `id`s that are shown).  Here's the query Views is generating:

```
SELECT My_Awesome_Table.title AS My_Awesome_Table_title,
  My_Awesome_Table.Department AS My_Awesome_Table_Department,
  My_Awesome_Table.description AS My_Awesome_Table_description,
  My_Awesome_Table.credits AS My_Awesome_Table_credits,
  My_Awesome_Table.id AS id
FROM {My_Awesome_Table} My_Awesome_Table
WHERE (( (My_Awesome_Table.Department NOT LIKE '' ESCAPE '\\') AND
  (My_Awesome_Table.title NOT LIKE '' ESCAPE '\\') ))
```

When I run this in phpMyAdmin, just removing the `{` and `}` from around `My_Awesome_Table`, it returns results and there is data in each column.

**Edit:** it's perhaps relevant to say that I made another custom View module for a different table in the same database, and it works fine.  I used that module as a base for this one, changing the module name, function prefixes, etc.

Comment: I know this is probably obvious, but whenever I have an issue like this it's usually because the function 'my_module' name is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: Try asking @ http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Clear cache, disable module 'my_module', save, then enable it back, save

In my development, I have to add this hook to make it works

```
function my_module_views_api() {
    return array('api'=>2.0);
}
```

Comment: This is right, hook_views_api must be implemented to tell Views you want it to pay attention to your module.